# Print with different settings of layer view?

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer

Using QGIS is it possible to print on the same paper two windows with different settings of layer?

I mean:

- **window1**: layer1 **ON** - layer2 OFF
- **window2**: layer1 OFF - layer2 **ON**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one can be a solution: "**lock layers for map item**"  from print composition/item properties. So you can set the layers as you need for window1 and click this setting then you update the project for window2 and update the view in the composition.

[image: print composition]

The problem of this solution is that when you reopen the project then the print composer you will lose the original settings